# How to break the one line of text and display it in 2 different labels in iphone

Tags: objective-c

How to break the one line of text and display it in 2 different labels.
For example i have a text says `"Have a happy week end"`. I wanted to print `"have a happy"` in one label and `"week end"` in the another label.

Comment: On which basis you are trying to split the string "Have a happy week end"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. You can split your sentence in words like this:

```
NSArray *words = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for(NSString *item in words)
{ 
.. 
}
```

or you can split your sentence with \n and display it in one label that supports multiple rows

```
lblMsg.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblMsg.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: his question is vague and not that specific soooo.. there is no correct answer because question is not asked properly :)

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a bit vague, but here is some code that splits a string (using spaces) into two equal parts if there is at least one space (the first part always being bigger if they cannot be equal). If there is no space, `firstHalf` will contain the whole string and `secondHalf` will be nil.

```
NSUInteger middle = string.length / 2;
NSUInteger length = string.length;
unichar theChar;
do {
    theChar = [string characterAtIndex:middle];
    middle++;
} while (middle < length && theChar != ' ');

NSString *firstHalf = nil;
NSString *secondHalf = nil;
if (theChar == ' ') {
    firstHalf = [string substringToIndex:middle];
    secondHalf = [string substringFromIndex:middle];
} else {
    firstHalf = string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure I exactly understand the question but if you want to display a string over two lines you could do this using one label showing two lines using "\n". Put "\n" at the end of happy (without quotes) so "have a happy \n week end".